# Simple Php Echo

Tags: php, forms, submit, echo

I am just starting to learn php, how would I initiate a echo statement after a submit button is pushed, or even a anchor tag.

Here is my code so far

```
form name="myform" method="get" actions="madlib01.php"

 Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />


     <input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

form

```
<?php

$Name = $_GET['name'];

$hello .= "Hello $Name";

echo $hello  //I would prefer the echo to happen after the submit button is hit

?>
```

Comment: You're trying to make the echo appear right after pressing the button. You can't do that with PHP, it's a server-side technology. Try JavaScript or another client-side technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct attribute for your form tag is "action", not "actions"

When the form is submitted, a new request is sent to the server (in your case, using GET).

So to do it all in one page:

form.php:

```
<form action="form.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?PHP
if (! empty($_GET['name'])){
   echo 'Hello, ' . $_GET['name'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to check if PHP has received your GET parameter using [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset) or [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists):

```
if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $Name = $_GET['name'];
    echo "Hello $Name";
}
```

or:

```
if(array_key_exists('name', $_GET) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $Name = $_GET['name'];
    echo "Hello $Name";
} else {
    //example: default to something if nothing has been passed
    echo "Hello Guest";
}
```

Also note, if you're submitting to the same page, you can omit the `action` attribute from your form tag altogether:

```
<form method="GET">
```

Comment: magic quotes "Hello $Name" should be discouraged as they are deprecated in future versions of php

Comment: @Jonathan Fingland, magic quotes is what PHP uses to automatically escape data - karim79's example has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

> echo $hello

You've just gained an HTML-injection vulnerability. If someone sends your user to:

```
http://www.example.com/madlib01.php?name=<script>stealYourCookies()</script>
```

you've got problems.

Yes, this is a My First PHP Script. That doesn't make security optional. This is a mistake every tutorial makes: teaching bad practice from the start, treating correctness (and security, which is a subset of correctness) as an optional extra.

The result is that most PHP code out there is full of holes. But there's no need for yours to be! Every time you place a pure-text string into a surrounding HTML context, escape it properly:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($hello);
```

I tend to define a function with a shorter name than ‘htmlspecialchars’ to do that for me, as I'm lazy.

```
<?php
    function h($text) {
        echo(htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES));
    }
    $name= '';
    if (isset($_REQUEST['name']))
        $name= trim($_REQUEST['name']);
?>

...

<?php if ($name!=='') { ?>
    <p> Hello, <?php h($name); ?>! </p>
<?php } ?>

<form method="get" action="madlib01.php">
    <p>
        <label for="namefield">Name:</label>
        <input id="namefield" type="text" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Now if you say your name is Mister <script>, the page will greet you exactly as such, angle brackets and all, instead of trying to run JavaScript. This is the correct output and thus also secure.

Comment: +1 for the h() function. They have that in Ruby too (you probably know)